# Hibernate - parent relationship for a @Embeddable to itself

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I wish to define an `@Embeddable` class called `Frame`. This class's lifecycle is related to an `@Entity` called `Master` which possesses a list of frames annotated as a `@ElementCollection`, i.e.

```
@Entity
public class Master extends ObjectWithId {
    private List<Frame> frameList;

    @ElementCollection
    @OrderColumn
    @OrderBy( "treeStage ASC" )
    public List<Frame> getFrameList() { return frameList; }
}

@Embeddable
@Access( AccessType.PROPERTY )
public class Frame {
    private int treeStage;
    @Basic
    @Column( nullable = false )
    public int getTreeStage() { return treeStage; }
}
```

But as suggested, the frameList has a tree structure, which means that each Frame has a parent except for the root. Hence I would like to add an attribute to the Frame which points to its parent as so:

```
@Embeddable
@Access( AccessType.PROPERTY )
public class Frame {
    private Frame parentFrame;
    private int treeStage;
    @Basic
    @Column( nullable = false )
    public int getTreeStage() { return treeStage; }
}
```

How could I annotate the `parentFrame` attribute?

For the moment I only get infinite loops because the embeddable objects embedds itself through the parentFrame attribute...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thinking is wrong. There is no way to refer to an `embeddable` inside itself, i.e. to have a field inside the `embeddable` which is of the type of the `embeddable` itself (the `Frame` in our case).

Hibernate cannot handle such a structure since it will seek to embedded itself and so forth till infinity.

`Frame` must be changed to an entity in order to keep this reference to its parent `Frame`.